# Javascript library for graph operations

Tags: graph, javascript

Is there any suggested javascript alternative(s) to pythons [pygraph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) or [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/)? It should be noted that visualization is not necessary (even prefered not to have this).

The library should be able to parse a format capable of retaining labeling and attributes on nodes and edges (DOT, GraphML?). It should support operations such as:

- Listing nodes and edges.
- Given a node, the edges which point in/out to/from it.
- Given a node or edge, return the attached attributes.
- Given two nodes that are connected, determine the most complete path. When running this operation a predicate function should be provided to determine if a node should be included in the search or not.

To put it in context, the web browser based application will traverse the graph from a pre-determined start node. Each node holds an attribute 'userValue' which is compared against conditions (rules?) held as attributes on the nodes out-edges. For the traversal to continue the edge condition must evaluate to true against 'userValue'. The graph will always contain a predetermined start and end (or goal) node.

Comment: Are there specific graph formats that need to be supported? Also if visualisation is not needed, then what kind of graph operations are needed to be supported?

Comment: You did not say what you want to do with this library, or in what context you need it to run.

Comment: Added more beef to the post in response to the previous comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

JSNetworkX
A port of the NetworkX graph library to JavaScript

http://felix-kling.de/JSNetworkX/